# selector isn't being recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, unrecognized-selector

I'm getting error when calling a selector named simIndex. This is the error message:

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba2ce80
```

This is my code

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/100000200918206/likes"
 parameters:nil
 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
 completionHandler:^(
 FBRequestConnection *connection,
 id results2,
 NSError *error
 ) {
 /* handle the result */
 if (error) {
 NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 } else {
 [self simIndex];
 }

 \
 }];
```

This is how I'm defining simIndex:

```
-(void) simIndex {
 //...
}
```

Comment: `[results2 count]` is breaking, what is `results2`??? Or what should it be??? String doesn't respond to `count` and it thinks `results2` is a string.

Comment: result2 is a NSMutableDictionary, it does not respond to count.

Comment: @andreamazz No, `results2` is really an `NSString` according to the exception. It certainly seems the OP expects it to be an `NSMutableDictionary`, but it's not. And `NSMutableDictionary` does in fact have a `count` method.

Comment: @user3511563 - why is your `n_friends_likes` variable declared as an `NSInteger *`? Get rid of the asterisk. It's a primitive type, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result2` is certainly not an `NSMutableDictionary`. Actually it is an `NSString` object. Check it and go from there.